# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

When pressing the button, i get this error message in the console:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined**

I thought, that the form ID is missing, but it is there, and its correct.

The javascript files, and all the javascipt is called at the page end, before the body closing tag, not in the head section.

My source code:

```
<form id="AllapotForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                              <table id="products" class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="tr_bold">
                                        <!--width="33.3%"-->
                                        <td class="left" >Létrehozva</td>
                                        <td class="left" >Állapot</td>
                                        <td class="left" >A megrendelő értesítve email-ben</td>
                                        <td class="left" >Megjegyzés</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="allapotok">
                                    <tr>
                                                    <td class="left">2018-03-18 20:16</td>
                                                    <td class="left">Feldolgozás alatt</td>
                                                    <td class="left">Nem</td>
                                                    <td class="left">Teszt állapot.</td>
                                                </tr>                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <img src="https://domain.hu/images/assets/preloader.gif" id="preloaderImage2" class="img-responsive" style="margin:10px auto;">

                                  <div class="form-group row">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-2">Állapot:</label>
                                      <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <select name="allapot" id="allapot" class="input input-select form-control">
                                            <option  value="3">Feldolgozva</option><option  value="2">Feldolgozás alatt</option><option  value="1">Függőben lévő</option><option  value="4">Kiküldve</option><option  value="5">Postázva</option><option  value="7">Sikertelen</option><option  selected="selected" value="9">Stornó</option><option  value="6">Teljesítve</option><option  value="10">Törölt</option><option  value="8">Visszafizetve</option><option  value="0">Új megrendelés</option>                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-2">Megrendelő értesítése email-ben:</label>
                                      <div class="col-md-2">
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="notify" id="notify" class="form-control"  />
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-2">Megjegyzés hozzáadása az email-hez:<span class="help">Amennyiben ezt bepipálja, a megjegyzés az ügyfélnek kiküldött üzenetbe is bele fog kerülni.</span></label>
                                      <div class="col-md-2">
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="add_text" id="add_text" class="form-control" />
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                      <label class="control-label col-md-2">Megjegyzés:</label>
                                      <div class="col-md-4">
                                         <textarea name="comment" id="comment"  rows="8" class="form-control" style="width: 99%"></textarea>
                                            <div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
                                                <a class="saveButton btn btn-primary" style="color:#fff" onclick="allapot_modosit();" id="history_button">Állapot módosítása</a>
                                            </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>



function allapot_modosit()
{
    var html;
    var RendelesID = 8;
    var RendelesUserEmail = "email@test.hu";
    var RendelesUserName = "name";

    var webshopEmail = "teszt@teszt.hu";
    var webshopName = "Teszt Webáruház";

    var Allapot = $( "#allapot option:selected" ).val();

    var Comment = $('#comment').val();

    if($("#notify").is(':checked')){var Notify = 1;}else{var Notify = 0;}
    if($("#add_text").is(':checked')){var AddToEmail = 1;}else{var AddToEmail = 0;}

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         cache: false,
         url: 'files/update_rendeles_allapot.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { RendelesID:RendelesID, Allapot:Allapot, Notify:Notify, AddToEmail:AddToEmail, Comment:Comment, RendelesUserEmail:RendelesUserEmail, RendelesUserName:RendelesUserName, webshopEmail:webshopEmail, webshopName:webshopName },
         beforeSend: function(){
            $('#preloaderImage2').show();
         },
         success: function(data)
         {
                html += '      <tr>';
                html += '        <td class="left">' + data.allapot_datetime + '</td>';
                html += '        <td class="left">' + data.allapot_name + '</td>';
                html += '        <td class="left">' + data.ertesites + '</td>';
                html += '        <td class="left">' + data.comment + '</td>';
                html += '      </tr>';
                $('#allapotok').append(html);
         },
         complete: function(){
            $('#preloaderImage2').hide();
            $('#AllapotForm')[0].reset();

         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On this line:

`$('#AllapotForm')[0].reset();`

Try removing the `[0]`. If you're querying an id, I don't think it returns a collection.

Comment: On second look, it's working in this pen: https://codepen.io/scraggo/pen/EENZJr?editors=0010
what does your development environment look like?